# How to rename sheet using google sheets api v4?

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a code that its purpose is to rename a specific sheet, but when executing the BatchUpdate and the code is crached, does anyone have any ideas?

```
        public void UpdateSheetName(string sheetName,string newSheetName)
    {
        //get sheet id by sheet name
        Spreadsheet spr = service.Spreadsheets.Get(SpreadsheetId).Execute();
        Sheet sh = spr.Sheets.Where(s => s.Properties.Title == sheetName).FirstOrDefault();
        int sheetId = (int)sh.Properties.SheetId;
        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest bussr = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();

        var request = new Request()
        {
              UpdateSpreadsheetProperties= new UpdateSpreadsheetPropertiesRequest(){
                   Properties=new SpreadsheetProperties()
                   {                      
                       Title= newSheetName,

                   },
                  Fields ="title"
               }

        };

        bussr.Requests = new List<Request>();
        bussr.Requests.Add(request);
        var bur = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(bussr, SpreadsheetId);
        bur.Execute();
    }
```

Error Message:
Invalid value at 'requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'updateSpreadsheetProperties' [400]

Comment: Do you know in which line the error is thrown?

Comment: When the BatchUpdated is executed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem, the problem was that I had used the wrong class, use UpdateSpreadsheetProperties instead of UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest

```
        var request = new Request()
        {
            UpdateSheetProperties =new UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest {
            Properties=new SheetProperties()
            {
                Title=newName,
                SheetId=sheetId

            },
                Fields = "Title"
            }


        };
```